# How to set the point, after which the ViewPager swipes to another View?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

If more than 50% of the follower of View B is visible,
on release the ViewPager will animate to the `View B` instead of goind back to `View A`.

How can I change this point of switching from 50% to x%?

Comment: have a look at the source code of ViewPager, PageAdapter, etc.

Comment: It's not 50% :), it's 40% and hard code by google.
reference: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.determineTargetPage%28int%2Cfloat%2Cint%2Cint%29

at line: 
else {
final float truncator = currentPage >= mCurItem ? 0.4f : 0.6f;
targetPage = (int) (currentPage + pageOffset + truncator);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding the [onScrollChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) function, here's an example:

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ViewPager vp, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    // We take the last son in the ViewPager
    View view = (View) vp.getChildAt(vp.getChildCount() - 1);

    if (diff <  view.getBottom()/2) {
        // do the animation
    }
}
```

Let me know if that worked or not (in order for me to know if I should remove the Answer from here).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own customized ViewPager and override the proper method with your own float-value. something like :

```
public CustomViewpager extends ViewPager {

@Override
private int determineTargetPage(int currentPage, float pageOffset, int velocity, int deltaX) {
    int targetPage;
    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mFlingDistance && Math.abs(velocity) > mMinimumVelocity) {
        targetPage = velocity > 0 ? currentPage : currentPage + 1;
    } else {

//change your values here for whatever you need for your purposes
        final float truncator = currentPage >= mCurItem ? 0.4f : 0.6f;

        targetPage = (int) (currentPage + pageOffset + truncator);
    }
    if (mItems.size() > 0) {
        final ItemInfo firstItem = mItems.get(0);
        final ItemInfo lastItem = mItems.get(mItems.size() - 1);
        // Only let the user target pages we have items for
        targetPage = Math.max(firstItem.position, Math.min(targetPage, lastItem.position));
    }
    return targetPage;
}
```

}